# Selenium's alert.getText() returns null

Tags: selenium, webdriver, alert

My scenario is that I have 2 windows, and the 2nd one shows an alert dialog of which I wanna check it's text.

Now I switch my WebDriver to the second window via:

```
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().iterator().next())
```

And then to make sure I get the correct Alert handle I use:

```
Alert alert = ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent().apply(driver);
String text = alert.getText();
```

but text is `null` even though the alert clearly contains a lot of text. 
I then tried to use

```
String text = driver.switchTo().alert().getText();
```

but it also returns `null`. 
Anybody of you encountered this problem? 
I have another alert dialog I'm checking but that test runs smooth, so I
guess it's related to my 2 windows, found a smiliar post in webdriver Google
Group but nobody has replied to it. I also tried to close the other window
and then check for the alert, but same result. The alert is present and
recognized, otherwise `alert` would have been `null`.